# smalltalk stepTime and step methods not working well

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Hi I have the following implemention of step in smalltalk

```
step
    |dx dy|

    [isPlaying]
    whileTrue:[
        speed := speed - 0.1.
        dx := speed / 15 * 4 * direction cos.
        dy := speed / 15 * 4 * direction sin.
        speed <= 0
        ifTrue:[isPlaying := false. self stopStepping.]
        ifFalse:[
                Transcript show:'(',dx,'@',dy,')';cr.
                whiteBall position: whiteBall position + (dx@dy).
                ].

        ].

    stepTime
        ^2.
```

and something very weird is happening when I open the transcript window and in the step method I have

```
Transcript show:'(',dx,'@',dy,')';cr.
```

the ball rectangle seems moving as an animation but if I close the transcript window and delete the line code

```
Transcript show:'(',dx,'@',dy,')';cr.
```

the ball rectangle seems to move right away from position A to position Y
Please help why is it happening?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: The `Transcript` call is slowing down the process between each step so you see an animation. When you remove `Transcript`, the steps are done at a very fast rate with much less delay so you don't see animation. It happens too quickly. You'd need some kind of time delay between position changes to see animation.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it I just remove the while loop inside the step method and it's working!!!!